# UIBarButtonItem with custom font is showing its text cropped

Tags: ios

I'm implementing a custom font in a UIBarButton item and the text looks cropped vertically. Has anyone experienced this? Is there a workaround to do?

[image]

Comment: Is the button high enough? Makes its frame a bit bigger/font smaller.

Comment: You can also try initWithCustomView method of UIBarButtonItem.. Just create a UIButton with title font and size then pass it to this method.. After that you just need to set it as the rightBarButtonItem of your navigation controller.